# Turn a 2D grid into a 'diamond' with LINQ - is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq

The other day I needed an algorithm to turn a 2D grid into a diamond (by effectively rotating 45 degrees), so I could deal with diagonal sequences as flat enumerables, like so:

```
    1 2 3        1         
    4 5 6  =>   4 2      
    7 8 9      7 5 3   
                8 6     
                 9
```

My algorithm is as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> RotateGrid<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> grid)
    {
        int bound = grid.Count() - 1;
        int upperLimit = 0;
        int lowerLimit = 0;

        Collection<Collection<T>> rotated = new Collection<Collection<T>>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= (bound * 2); i++)
        {
            Collection<T> row = new Collection<T>();

            for (int j = upperLimit, k = lowerLimit; j >= lowerLimit || k <= upperLimit; j--, k++)
            {
                row.Add(grid.ElementAt(j).ElementAt(k));
            }

            rotated.Add(row);

            if (upperLimit == bound)
                lowerLimit++;

            if (upperLimit < bound)
                upperLimit++;
        }

        return rotated;
    }
```

Can this be achieved in a more concise format using LINQ?

.. or even just a more concise format? :)

Comment: Cant you get input as standard 2D array? Is it necessary for output to be lazy? I dont think using LINQ would be good idea. Also, how would rectangular input array look like in outpu?

Comment: I'm interested to see any other implementations that achieve the same thing, but specifically I'd like to see a LINQ implementation - I know you can perform pretty much any transformation you like with LINQ but I couldn't get one to work here, partly I think because I needed to 'grow and shrink' the diamond as I worked over the grid..

Comment: I think with involvement of some math, LINQ would be possible.

Comment: I think the way enumerators are built it's not the best option to use LINQ for this. I think it's better to use a (generic) rectangular array as input, and output a (generic) jagged array. You could of course make it an extension method, but I doubt enumerators are the best option for doing so.

Comment: I agree. Especialy for enforcing, that input MUST be rectangle/square. I cant imagine doing this with jagged array.

Comment: Of course it's possible with a non-rectangular array, but it'd totally mess up the image, and I think that's not what you want. The best approach for this would I think be to diagonally walk through the rectangular array.

Comment: Validation of 'squareness' of the grid happens elsewhere..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
void Main()
{
    var lists = new string[] { "123", "456", "789" };

    foreach (var seq in RotateGrid(lists))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", seq));
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> RotateGrid<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> grid) 
{
    int rows = grid.Count();
    int cols = grid.First().Count();
    return 
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, rows + cols - 1)
        select (
            from j in Enumerable.Range(0, i + 1)
            where i - j < rows && j < cols
            select grid.ElementAt(i - j).ElementAt(j)
        );
}
```

Output:

```
1
4, 2
7, 5, 3
8, 6
9
```

This gets a lot cleaner and more performant if you can assume `IList<T>`s instead of just `IEnumerable<T>`.  I'm thinking of a more efficient approach (not using `.ElementAt`) that would work with IEnumerable` also, which I will post if I manage to write it.

**Update**:

Here's my more practical version, that still manages to shoe-horn in a fair amount of linq.  It's a reasonably efficient algorithm, in that it only creates an enumerator once for each `IEnumerable`.

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> RotateGrid<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> grid) 
{
    var enumerators = new LinkedList<IEnumerator<T>>();
    var diagonal = 
        from e in enumerators
        where e.MoveNext()
        select e.Current;
    foreach (var row in grid)
    {
        enumerators.AddFirst(row.GetEnumerator());
        yield return diagonal.ToArray();
    }

    T[] output;
    while (true)
    {
        output = diagonal.ToArray();
        if(output.Length == 0) yield break;
        yield return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. But its more use of clever math, than LINQ itself.

Comment: I still dont think this can be even called LINQ. But whatever, you got your answer.

Comment: @Euphoric: I'm working on a slightly more practical version that has a loop in it.  Perhaps that will satisfy you.  I would never use this is in practice as it's wildly inefficient.

Comment: @Euphoric This is probably considered linq because it uses enumerators, yet I agree that it isn't linq, because the beauty of linq is that it doesn't have to know everything to work. This version will not be very fast, I'm also trying something, but it'll require caching too... I wonder if it's possible without caching through writing your own enumerator... I mean it should be possible... Well at least if you know the length by start, without having to count.

Comment: @Recursive Dude you're my hero, not that I need it, but finally someone that understands the beauty of keeping enumerators fast :), and that realizes that they are rather a state class then just a little bit of yield returning! (+1) Though for larger collections it might be wise to use a faster collection then `List<T>`, maybe `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as `Dictionary<int, T>` in this case, so that you have an O(1) lookup. According to [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time) article, if there's more then 4 elements lookups are faster with dictionaries.

Comment: @Aidiakapi: Thanks.  I think a linked list would be ideal, since you need to iterate, and you're always inserting at the front, but yes `List<T>` is probably not ideal, asymptotically.

Comment: @Recursive `LinkedList<T>` might also be an option yes, but I think `Dictionary<int, T>` would be causing the identical behavior, just being a lot faster from 4+ elements (assuming the benchmark is correct).

Comment: @Aidiakapi:  I switched it to `LinkedList<T>`.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I think that should improve performance for large data sets.

Comment: @Aidiakapi: What benchmark is that?  I'd be interested to see it.  A dictionary doesn't intuitively have any significant advantage in insertion or iteration over a linked list that I can see.

Comment: @Recursive No problem :) I must say this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Recursive - I don't 'get' your second solution. What happens with multiple yield statements?

Comment: @flesh: Whenever a `yield return` is encountered, that value is "streamed" back to the caller.  Each value is one `IEnumerable<T>` diagonal "slice", so when the method is considered in total, it becomes the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` collection of slices.  Once all the enumerators have been created, it needs to check to see whether all of the enumerables have been exhuasted.  When they are, it breaks out, ending the outer `IEnumerable`.  One advantage of this approach is that it works with jagged arrays.

Comment: OK, thanks, it's clearer now, though how does `while(true)` ever complete?

Comment: @flesh: when `yield break` executes, the method terminates, never to resume.